# How to edit and add Customer Services, Extras & My Account pages from admin side in Opencart

Tags: open-source, opencart

I have searched everywhere but not succeed. Does anybody know? Please help me.

Comment: What is this question about? I do not understand. Try OpenCart forums, this site is for developers...

Comment: Mr shadyyx, i know this site is for what. And i mean to ask that above mention pages does not accessible from admin side of opencart then how to do coding in which file. I have done many projects in Wordpress and Jommla CMS but newbie in opencart. If you know about opencart CMS then it is basic question to give answer...understand!!

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add custom pages for them. You need to edit the templates directly through FTP, if you need new pages add them in the controller and also add the .tpl file for it too. You do need to know what your doing though so you should probably contact a developer if you need it to be done. It is basic MVC style coding so almost any PHP developer should be able to pick it up quite quick.

Comment: MVC isn't something that any PHP developer knows very well and even the MVC in OpenCart is done in completely different way regarding most of present MVC frameworks.